# WETH on Uniswap forks on other chains

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap

I was wondering what WETH() does on Uniswap forks on other chains, for example if I want to create a liquidity pair on Pancakeswap it might be something like this:

address lpPair = IPancakeFactory(router.factory()).createPair(address(this),router.WETH());

I don't understand what WETH() does here. Does it mean wrapped ETH on BSC, or wrapped BNB, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be the Wrapped Gas token on that network.

For example:

Wrapped ETH on ETH,

Wrapped BNB on BSC,

Wrapped MATIC on POLYGON,

Etc..